# Select distinct and max on a table with similar values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a problem with a stored procedure that uses multiple tables, but One of my tables has multiple rows per employee ID. I need the table to return the CoverageEndDate as a null value, unless CoverageEndDate has a date. Then I want the date and not the null. When I use a distinct I get one of each if both exist

Here is part of the table for 1 empID

[image]

Here is what I want

[image]

I can get the date only by using this basic call, but it does not work in the stored procedure:
SELECT max(EmployeeID), max(CoverageEndDate)
from EmployeeCoverageValue
where EmployeeID = 5844

Here is the query(I put --CoverageEndDate where referenced):

```
        ALTER PROCEDURE [EligibilityExport_ExportCurrentEmployeeData_Select] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@TerminationDeadLine datetime = null
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @EligibilityExportDetailRows as [udtEligibilityExportDetail]
DECLARE @EligibilityExportEmployeePlans as [udtEmployeePlansToExport]
DECLARE @Header as varchar(MAX) = ''

SELECT DISTINCT @Header += name + CHAR(9)
  FROM sys.columns
 WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('[fn_EligibilityExport_Export_RowData]')


INSERT @EligibilityExportDetailRows
    SELECT DISTINCT eed.[EligibilityExportID], eed.[EmployeePlanID], eed.[EmployeePlanValueID], 
        eed.[EmployeeCoverageValueID], eed.[EmployeeInformationPersonalValueID],
        eed.[DependentValueID], eed.[EmployeeID]
    FROM [EligibilityExportDetail] eed
        INNER JOIN (
                SELECT EligibilityExportDetailID = MAX(EligibilityExportDetailID), EmployeeID
                FROM [EligibilityExportDetail]
                GROUP BY EmployeeID
            ) AS eed_max 
            ON eed_max.EligibilityExportDetailID = eed.EligibilityExportDetailID

INSERT @EligibilityExportEmployeePlans
    SELECT DISTINCT EligibilityExportID = eedr.EligibilityExportID, 
        EmployeePlanID = MAX(EmployeePlanID), 
        EmployeeID = EmployeeID, 
        AsOfDate = ee.CreateDate
    FROM @EligibilityExportDetailRows eedr
        INNER JOIN [EligibilityExport] ee
            ON ee.EligibilityExportID = eedr.EligibilityExportID
    GROUP BY eedr.EligibilityExportID, eedr.EmployeeID, ee.CreateDate

--Select employees
SELECT DISTINCT Selected = CAST(0 as bit), vEI.EmployeeID, vEI.LastName, vEI.FirstName, vEI.MiddleName, 
    vEI.Address1, vEI.City, vEI.State, vEI.ZipCode, vEi.HireDate, vEi.TerminationDate, 
--CoverageEndDate
    CoverageEndDate = eCV.CoverageEndDate,
--CoverageEndDate
    DivisionNumber = dv.DivisionNumber,
    DivisionName = ISNULL(dv.DivisionName,'None'), 
    DepartmentName = ISNULL(dp.DepartmentName,'None'), 
    WorkcenterName = ISNULL(wc.WorkcenterName,'None'),
    ExportRowData = CAST (
         fnEE.EmployeeNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.LastName  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.FirstName  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.MiddleName  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Suffix  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.SocialSecurityNumber  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.DateOfBirth  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.EE_Gender  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Address1  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Address2  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.City  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.State  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.ZipCode + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.HireDate  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Department  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.EffectiveDate  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.CoverageCode + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.CobraEventCode + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_Gender+ CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_Gender + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_Gender + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_Gender + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_Gender + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_Gender
    as varchar(MAX)),
    Header = REPLACE(@Header, 'EligibilityExportID' + CHAR(9) + 'EmployeePlanID' + CHAR(9), '')
FROM @EligibilityExportEmployeePlans ee_ep
    INNER JOIN v_EmployeeInformation vEI
        ON vEI.EmployeeID = ee_ep.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN [fn_EligibilityExport_Export_RowData] 
        ( @EligibilityExportDetailRows, @EligibilityExportEmployeePlans ) fnEE
            ON fnEE.EmployeePlanID = ee_ep.EmployeePlanID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Division dv
        ON vEI.DivisionID = dv.DivisionID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Department dp
        ON vEI.DepartmentID = dp.DepartmentID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Workcenter wc
        ON vEI.WorkcenterID = wc.WorkCenterID
--CoverageEndDate           
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeCoverageValue eCV
        ON eCV.EmployeeID = vEI.EmployeeID
WHERE @terminationDeadLine <= eCV.CoverageEndDate OR eCV.CoverageEndDate IS NULL
--CoverageEndDate
ORDER BY CoverageEndDate DESC, DivisionNumber, DepartmentName, WorkcenterName, LastName, FirstName
```

Comment: Looks like what you want is: SELECT EmployeeID, max(CoverageEndDate) FROM ... GROUP BY EmployeeID

Comment: Whenever I do that I get this error message: 
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure EligibilityExport_ExportCurrentEmployeeData_Select, Line 56
Column 'v_EmployeeInformation.EmployeeID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: well, the error message pretty says, what you need to do.
either use an aggregate-function on the column v_EmployeeInformation.EmployeeID
or add the column to the group by clause
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

TY for the help :) apparently the division, department, and work center were removed from the database a while back. here is what I ended up doing in code:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Selected = CAST(0 as bit), vEI.EmployeeID, vEI.LastName, vEI.FirstName, vEI.MiddleName, 
    vEI.Address1, vEI.City, vEI.State, vEI.ZipCode, vEi.HireDate, vEi.TerminationDate, 
    CoverageEndDate = ISNULL(MAX(eCV.CoverageEndDate), ''),
    DivisionNumber = vEI.DivisionNumber,
    --DivisionName = ISNULL(dv.DivisionName,'None'), 
    --DepartmentName = ISNULL(dp.DepartmentName,'None'), 
    --WorkcenterName = ISNULL(wc.WorkcenterName,'None'),
    ExportRowData = CAST (
         fnEE.EmployeeNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.LastName  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.FirstName  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.MiddleName  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Suffix  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.SocialSecurityNumber  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.DateOfBirth  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.EE_Gender  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Address1  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Address2  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.City  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.State  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.ZipCode + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.HireDate  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Department  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.EffectiveDate  + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.CoverageCode + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.CobraEventCode + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent2_Gender+ CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent3_Gender + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent4_Gender + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent5_Gender + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent6_Gender + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_Name + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_DateOfBirth + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_EffectiveDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_TerminationDate + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_Relationship + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_SocialSecurityNumber + CHAR(9) +
         fnEE.Dependent7_Gender
    as varchar(MAX)),
    Header = REPLACE(@Header, 'EligibilityExportID' + CHAR(9) + 'EmployeePlanID' + CHAR(9), '')
FROM @EligibilityExportEmployeePlans ee_ep
    INNER JOIN v_EmployeeInformation vEI
        ON vEI.EmployeeID = ee_ep.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN [fn_EligibilityExport_Export_RowData] 
        ( @EligibilityExportDetailRows, @EligibilityExportEmployeePlans ) fnEE
            ON fnEE.EmployeePlanID = ee_ep.EmployeePlanID
    --LEFT OUTER JOIN MAIN.Global.dbo.Division dv
    --  ON vEI.DivisionID = dv.DivisionID
    --LEFT OUTER JOIN MAIN.Global.dbo.Department dp
    --  ON vEI.DepartmentID = dp.DepartmentID
    --LEFT OUTER JOIN MAIN.Global.dbo.Workcenter wc
    --  ON vEI.WorkcenterID = wc.WorkCenterID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeCoverageValue eCV
        ON eCV.EmployeeID = vEI.EmployeeID
WHERE @terminationDeadLine <= eCV.CoverageEndDate OR eCV.CoverageEndDate IS NULL
GROUP BY vEI.EmployeeID, vEI.LastName, vEI.FirstName, vEI.MiddleName, vEI.Address1, vEI.City, vEI.State, vEI.ZipCode, vEI.HireDate, vEI.TerminationDate, vEI.DivisionNumber,
         fnEE.EmployeeNumber,
         fnEE.LastName ,
         fnEE.FirstName ,
         fnEE.MiddleName ,
         fnEE.Suffix ,
         fnEE.SocialSecurityNumber ,
         fnEE.DateOfBirth ,
         fnEE.EE_Gender ,
         fnEE.Address1 ,
         fnEE.Address2 ,
         fnEE.City ,
         fnEE.State ,
         fnEE.ZipCode,
         fnEE.HireDate ,
         fnEE.Department ,
         fnEE.EffectiveDate ,
         fnEE.TerminationDate,
         fnEE.CoverageCode,
         fnEE.CobraEventCode,
         fnEE.Dependent2_Name,
         fnEE.Dependent2_DateOfBirth,
         fnEE.Dependent2_EffectiveDate,
         fnEE.Dependent2_TerminationDate,
         fnEE.Dependent2_Relationship,
         fnEE.Dependent2_SocialSecurityNumber,
         fnEE.Dependent2_Gender,
         fnEE.Dependent3_Name,
         fnEE.Dependent3_DateOfBirth,
         fnEE.Dependent3_EffectiveDate,
         fnEE.Dependent3_TerminationDate,
         fnEE.Dependent3_Relationship,
         fnEE.Dependent3_SocialSecurityNumber,
         fnEE.Dependent3_Gender,
         fnEE.Dependent4_Name,
         fnEE.Dependent4_DateOfBirth,
         fnEE.Dependent4_EffectiveDate,
         fnEE.Dependent4_TerminationDate,
         fnEE.Dependent4_Relationship,
         fnEE.Dependent4_SocialSecurityNumber,
         fnEE.Dependent4_Gender,
         fnEE.Dependent5_Name,
         fnEE.Dependent5_DateOfBirth,
         fnEE.Dependent5_EffectiveDate,
         fnEE.Dependent5_TerminationDate,
         fnEE.Dependent5_Relationship,
         fnEE.Dependent5_SocialSecurityNumber,
         fnEE.Dependent5_Gender,
         fnEE.Dependent6_Name,
         fnEE.Dependent6_DateOfBirth,
         fnEE.Dependent6_EffectiveDate,
         fnEE.Dependent6_TerminationDate,
         fnEE.Dependent6_Relationship,
         fnEE.Dependent6_SocialSecurityNumber,
         fnee.Dependent6_Gender,
         fnEE.Dependent7_Name,
         fnEE.Dependent7_DateOfBirth ,
         fnEE.Dependent7_EffectiveDate,
         fnEE.Dependent7_TerminationDate ,
         fnEE.Dependent7_Relationship,
         fnEE.Dependent7_SocialSecurityNumber,
         fnEE.Dependent7_Gender
ORDER BY CoverageEndDate DESC, DivisionNumber, LastName, FirstName
```